# Reference updates conflics with contentrules

Tags: plone, contentrules

I created a content rule with the "Object modified" trigger.

The rule has a "Workflow state" condition (but it might have a "Content type" one or any context-based condition).

The rule works fine BUT when the object's references are changed. This may happen when adding internal links or images in TinyMCE or when modifying the "related content" field for instance.

When updating references, a new object (the reference) is created (or deleted) in a special `at_references` folder associated with the original object.

Unfortunately, this creation fires the content rule, but in the context of the references folder. So the condition expression is not true and the action isn't executed.

Apparently, the rule is fired just once per request so it's not fired again for the original object that was modified.

Is this a bug or a feature?

Is there any workaround for this?

Do you have any suggestion of how to get my rule working?

Comment: the question is why do you need such rule? what are you trying to accomplish with it?

Comment: Whenever the object is modified, images inserted in TinyMCE are automatically published. This is done via a new custom action. But no matter if I solve this (I could dereference and get the image) the problem remains: object modified rules aren't executed in the object's context if references are changed.

Comment: current versions of Plone use no workflow on images, perhaps that's the best way to solve your issue.

Comment: I need a workflow for images. No matter that, the problem persists.